# Unable to get HTML formatting to work in GMAIL

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I have a powershell script that sends out an HTML formatted email, the formatting looks perfect in Outlook but does not work in GMAIL, any suggestions? The HTML used is:

```
#HTML 
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 10px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Is it a particular styling issue, or doesn't the HTML part display at all?

Comment: The html styling is not displaying at all. The text is in rows with no table. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GMail tends to prefer inline styles. As such:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
     <tr style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: don't you mean `border-collapse: collapse`?